# how to update rollup smummary function like subtraction & count on Monthly forecast

Tags: apex

Here we have two object, Opportunity & monthly forecast.
Opportunity is child object & monthly forecast is parent object.

In Salesforce monthly forecast is created for users. When opportunity owner changed from one user to another user, that opportunity amount will then be deducted from old owner monthly forecast & added to new owner forecast. Also same for no of opportunity (count) function.

Below we have written apex code for it, here for addition & deletion its worked but if we changed owner then subtraction of amount from old owner monthly forecast record will not be recalcuated.

```java
public class oppOwnerChange {
    
    public static void ownerChange(list<Opportunities__c> newOppList, map<Id, Opportunities__c> OldMapOpplist){
        Decimal wonAmount = 0;
        Decimal lostAmount = 0;
        Decimal pipeAmount = 0;
        
        Decimal wonoldAmount = 0;
        Decimal lostoldAmount = 0;
        Decimal pipeoldAmount = 0;

        for(Opportunities__c opp :newOppList){
            if(opp.OwnerId != OldMapOpplist.get(opp.Id).OwnerId){
                Monthly_Forecast__c newmon = [SELECT Id, Name, Actual_Revenue__c, Month__c, Fiscal_Year__c, Owner__c, In_Pipeline_Revenue__c, 
                                              Closed_Lost_Amount__c, No_Of_Opportunities__c, Expected_Revenue__c, Quarterly_Forecast__c, Fiscal_Quarter__c, 
                                              Yearly_Forecast__c FROM Monthly_Forecast__c WHERE Id = :opp.Monthly_Forecast__c];
                Monthly_Forecast__c oldMon = [SELECT Id, Name, Actual_Revenue__c, Month__c, Fiscal_Year__c, Owner__c, In_Pipeline_Revenue__c, 
                                              Closed_Lost_Amount__c, No_Of_Opportunities__c, Expected_Revenue__c, Quarterly_Forecast__c, Fiscal_Quarter__c, 
                                              Yearly_Forecast__c FROM Monthly_Forecast__c WHERE Id = :OldMapOpplist.get(opp.Id).Monthly_Forecast__c];
                system.debug('oldMon>>>>'+oldMon);
                List<Opportunities__c> oppList = new List<Opportunities__c>([SELECT Id, Amount__c, StageName__c FROM Opportunities__c WHERE Monthly_Forecast__c = :newmon.Id]);
                List<Opportunities__c> oppOldList = new List<Opportunities__c>([SELECT Id, Amount__c, StageName__c FROM Opportunities__c WHERE Monthly_Forecast__c = :oldMon.Id]);
                system.debug('oppOldList>>>>'+oppOldList);

                for(Opportunities__c op :oppList){                    
                    if(op.StageName__c == 'Closed Lost'){
                        lostAmount = lostAmount + op.Amount__c;                        
                    }
                    else if(op.StageName__c == 'Closed Won'){
                        wonAmount = wonAmount + op.Amount__c;
                    }
                    else{
                        pipeAmount = pipeAmount + op.Amount__c;
                    }
                    
                    //for old owner forecast records
                    
                    /*if(OldMapOpplist.get(opp.Id).StageName__c == 'Closed Lost'){
                        amount = oldMon.Closed_Lost_Amount__c - OldMapOpplist.get(opp.Id).Amount__c;
                        oldMon.Closed_Lost_Amount__c = amount;
                        oldMon.No_Of_Opportunities__c = oppList.size();
                        update oldMon;
                        
                    }
                    else if(OldMapOpplist.get(opp.Id).StageName__c == 'Closed Won'){
                        amount = oldMon.Actual_Revenue__c - OldMapOpplist.get(opp.Id).Amount__c;
                        oldMon.Actual_Revenue__c = amount;
                        oldMon.No_Of_Opportunities__c = oppList.size();
                        update oldMon;
                        
                    }
                    else{
                        amount = oldMon.In_Pipeline_Revenue__c - OldMapOpplist.get(opp.Id).Amount__c;
                        oldMon.In_Pipeline_Revenue__c = amount;
                        oldMon.No_Of_Opportunities__c = oppList.size();
                        update oldMon;
                        
                    }*/
                }

                newmon.Closed_Lost_Amount__c = lostAmount;
                newmon.Actual_Revenue__c = wonAmount;
                newmon.In_Pipeline_Revenue__c = pipeAmount;
                newmon.No_Of_Opportunities__c = oppList.size();
                update newmon;
                
                for(Opportunities__c op :oppOldList){
                    if(op.StageName__c == 'Closed Lost'){
                        lostoldAmount = lostoldAmount + op.Amount__c;
                    }
                    else if(op.StageName__c == 'Closed Won'){
                        wonoldAmount = wonoldAmount + op.Amount__c;
                    }
                    else{
                        pipeoldAmount = pipeoldAmount + op.Amount__c;
                    }
                }

                system.debug('wonoldAmount>>>>'+wonoldAmount);
                oldMon.Closed_Lost_Amount__c = lostoldAmount;
                oldMon.Actual_Revenue__c = wonoldAmount;
                oldMon.In_Pipeline_Revenue__c = pipeoldAmount;
                oldMon.No_Of_Opportunities__c = oppOldList.size();
                update oldMon;                
            }
        }
    }

    public static void beforeDelete(list<Opportunities__c> newOppList){
        Decimal amount;
        for(Opportunities__c opp :newOppList){
            Monthly_Forecast__c newmon = [SELECT Id, Name, Actual_Revenue__c, Month__c, Fiscal_Year__c, Owner__c, In_Pipeline_Revenue__c, 
                                          Closed_Lost_Amount__c, No_Of_Opportunities__c, Expected_Revenue__c, Quarterly_Forecast__c, Fiscal_Quarter__c, 
                                          Yearly_Forecast__c FROM Monthly_Forecast__c WHERE Id = :opp.Monthly_Forecast__c];
            
            List<Opportunities__c> oppList = new List<Opportunities__c>([SELECT Id FROM Opportunities__c WHERE Monthly_Forecast__r.Id = :newmon.Id]);
            
            if(opp.StageName__c == 'Closed Lost'){
                amount = newmon.Closed_Lost_Amount__c - opp.Amount__c;
                newmon.Closed_Lost_Amount__c = amount;
                newmon.No_Of_Opportunities__c = oppList.size();
                update newmon;
            }
            else if(opp.StageName__c == 'Closed Won'){
                amount = newmon.Actual_Revenue__c - opp.Amount__c;
                newmon.Actual_Revenue__c = amount;
                newmon.No_Of_Opportunities__c = oppList.size();
                update newmon;
            }
            else{
                amount = newmon.In_Pipeline_Revenue__c - opp.Amount__c;
                newmon.In_Pipeline_Revenue__c = amount;
                newmon.No_Of_Opportunities__c = oppList.size();
                update newmon;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, it's generally better to recalculate from scratch than to try to do incremental updates. A large part of that sentiment stems from the fact that there are ways for a trigger to be executed multiple times (working on the same set of records) in a transaction.

Field update actions with workflow rules (which Salesforce is sunsetting), Process Builder, or after-save record-triggered flows can all cause that to happen. If it does happen, you're almost certainly going to apply the incrementing/decrementing twice.

Detecting when your trigger is "running again" is not an easy problem to solve, and you may not be able to control if one of those declarative tools are used. It's just easier to assume that they are being used, and doing a full recalculation every time as a defensive coding measure.

In general, what you need to do is:

- Loop over the old records (update/delete) and gather the ownerIds
- Loop over the new records (insert/update) and gather the ownerIds
- Use the combined set of ownerIds to query for Opportunities, and use grouping + aggregate functions to do the heavy lifting

Queries and DML inside of loops is bad. There are a few, limited situations where it'd be ok, but this is definitely not one of them.

You'll also probably need an additional query to get the `Monthly_Forecast__c` record for each of those users.

While you *can* do things like record counting and summing in Apex, this is generally something I try to have SOQL take care of for me instead. It usually ends up making your code shorter (which is nice because it's less work *and* less chance to introduce a bug). Assuming that you have gathered all of the owner Ids, that could look something like this:

```java
for(AggregateResult aggResult :[SELECT 
                                    COUNT(Id) recordCount, SUM(Amount) totalAmount, OwnerId, StageName
                                FROM 
                                    Opportunity 
                                WHERE
                                    CreatedDate = THIS_MONTH AND OwnerId IN :ownerIdSet
                                GROUP BY ROLLUP(OwnerId, StageName)]){
    // Using just "GROUP BY" could still work, but it would be slightly more work
    //   to get the total number of Opps across all StageNames.

    // Using "GROUP BY ROLLUP" means that the query will give you that total as
    //   well with a row that has the ownerId and a literal null as the StageName.
    // See the documentation for examples: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_rollup.htm

    // The main downside to using GROUP BY to get an AggregateResult is that
    //   you need to use .get() and explicit typecasts to get useful data
    Id workingOwnerId = (Id)aggResult.get('OwnerId');
    String stageName = (String)aggResult.get('StageName')
    Decimal totalAmount = (Decimal)aggResult.get('totalAmount');
    Integer oppCount = (Integer)aggResult.get('recordCount');

    // Assuming you have a map of Monthly Forecasts with the ownerId as the key
    // Further, if you're only gathering records for the ownerIds that you previously
    //   gathered, you won't need a separate collection to store the updates
    //   for the forecasts.
    Monthly_Forecast__c forecast = forecastsByOwnerId.get(workingOwnerId);

    switch on stageName {
        when 'Closed Won' {
            forecast.Actual_Revenue__c = totalAmount;
        }
        when 'Closed Lost' {
            forecast.Closed_Lost_Amount__c = totalAmount;
        }
        when null {
            forecast.No_of_Opportunities__c = oppCount;

            // The null case will _always_ be the last row for a given
            // OwnerId, so it is safe (and correct) to subtract the other
            //   amounts.
            // The one "gotcha" here is that you should ensure that
            //   Actual_Revenue__c and Closed_Lost_Amount__c are explicitly set
            //   to 0 when you're building that map (in case there are no
            //   opps in one or both of those stages)
            forecast.In_Pipeline_Revenue__c = totalAmount - forecast.Actual_Revenue__c - forecast.Closed_Lost_Amount__c = totalAmount;
        }
    }
}

// DML outside of all loops
update forecastsByOwnerId.values();
```

That's 26 lines without comments, liberally counted (though gathering the ownerIds would add another 7, and querying forecasts + building the forecast map would take another 6, for a total of 39 lines)
compared to the 60+ lines in your current, incomplete approach.

This code should be able to cover the insert, update, and delete cases. You just need to handle your new/old opp collections appropriately (i.e. be sure to have some null checks so you don't run into a Null Pointer Exception trying to iterate over `newOppList` in a delete trigger context)